# Decomposition of double-precision float into bytes using union in C

Tags: c, types, unions

I'm fairly new to C programming so please excuse any coding faux pas, etc.

I have a union defined that looks like this:

```
union meh {
    double foo;
    char bar[8];
};
```

Then I do something like this:

```
meh firstOne;
meh otherOne;

char blah[8];
double whatever;

firstOne.foo = 0.12345;
blah = firstOne.bar;

otherOne.bar = blah;
whatever = otherOne.foo;
```

And what I'm trying to figure out is: Will 'whatever' equal 0.12345?

(Just to clarify - `sizeof(double)` is 8 bytes on my machine - don't know if that's true everywhere.)

I know the obvious thing to do would be to just run it and try myself, but unfortunately I'm not in a position to do that. I'm also interested about the mechanics behind the code here.

Thanks so much for your time and help - it is much appreciated!

EDIT: From comments so far, it looks like I'm an idiot and

```
blah = firstOne.bar;
```

should be

```
strcpy(blah, firstOne.bar);
```

instead.  Sorry about that!

Comment: "I know the obvious thing to do would be to just run it any try myself, but unfortunately I'm not in a position to do that."  Why not?  It's not difficult to download gcc or Visual C++ (or clang or...) and use them.

Comment: I'm using a machine that has none of those and I don't have the admin privileges necessary to install them.  I know, it's really stupid.

Comment: That's awesome, I'll definitely try that in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `whatever` will be `0.12345` if you fix the errors. If you get around to testing it yourself, here's some de-uglified example code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

// use more descriptive names
union d2b
{
    double value;
    char bytes[sizeof (double)]; // avoid magic numbers
};

int main(void)
{
    const double TEST_VALUE = 0.12345;

    // don't omit the union keyword in C (not necessary in C++)
    union d2b src, dest;
    src.value = TEST_VALUE;

    // arrays are not lvalues, ie you can't assign to array variables
    // use memcpy() instead of strcpy() for arbitrary binary data
    memcpy(dest.bytes, src.bytes, sizeof dest.bytes);

    // assert, the foundation of test-driven development in C
    assert(dest.value == TEST_VALUE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `blah = firstOne.bar` would compile - you're trying to copy an entire array which it wouldn't like you doing.  You'd need to use `memcpy` to copy all the array data. But saying you DID do that (in both places you're trying to copy the char array), I'd say `whatever` *would* end up equalling 0.12345.

Answer (score 0):

Make that:

```
union meh {
    double foo;
    char bar[ sizeof(double) ];
};
```